# Nodemon detects changes, says it is restarting but doesn't actually restart

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

It was working before but it stopped. If I crash the express app in the app.js file, nodemon will restart at first, but once the app.listen() is executed it won't restart. I tried to isolate every element on the app.js file but the behavior continues. I also added some package recently and I deleted them to see if they caused the behavior but it remains.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^4.3.0",
    "google-finance": "^0.1.10",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.7",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "range": "0.0.3",
    "round-to": "^2.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are using `nodemon`, because  the `start` command should be:

```
"start": "nodemon app"
```

Comment: Yes. Anyway isn't the script executed only in deployment? Because I can delete it or replace it to nodemon app and it has no effect on the behavior of the app.